# How create and send an user activation email in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in cakephp. So I would like to know about how will create an email activation link in Cakephp 2.x and how will send it? Please anybody give an example

Comment: I use one-time-valid tokens: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/25/tools-plugin-part1-codekey/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use verification link as hash tag to generate from username or email address which should be unique to your entire application.

here i am giving you just idea how to achieve this task, but you must have to try with your self to do something by yourself

just go throw [this link](http://www.nikatrex.com/blog/?p=300) and understand how they actually sending email verification to user and how they verify this after click on email.